# Wordpress: Retrieve data from plugin and display it

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, hook

I'm new to Wordpress and somewhat struggling to find out where to actually put my site's functionality (i.e. something like retrieving data from database).

After doing some research I came to the conclusion that a good approach would be to put the code into a functionality plugin. The plugin would call a java backend which then returns the neccessary data.

Problem now is that I don't know what would be a good way to actually get the data which the plugin retrieves and display it using some display logic in the theme's php files.

I came across hooks, problem is that the action hook does not return anything, and the filter hook does not seem to be designed for that purpose.

Comment: You can write your own plugin and call its functionalities in your template files. Let's say you have a singleton class in your plugin called "MyClass" with the function `function Hello() {
    return MyClass::instance();
}`, you can call it's public methods in template with `Hello()->myPublicMethod()`.

Comment: is that considered good practice?

Comment: Some popular WP plugins use that behaviour, like Custom Field Suite. The "bad practices" would be to not use WP functions to interact with WP tables inside the plugin for example.

Comment: alright I'll try that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Increase your upload size by following the directions on the 1&1 helpcenter.

1. Open cPanel
2. Go to file manger
3. Browse to the www directory
4. Create a file named php.ini
5. Add the lines add `ini_set("upload_max_filesize","100M");
   ini_set("post_max_size","100M");`

Done! Please call 1&1 if you have any issues with this, they can walk you through it.

See http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/change-php-directives-a660257.html